Simplified scenario: evaporative cooling vs convective heating between water and air
While thinking through this question I thought of a simplified scenario that would model one of the extremes:
A body of water with mass $M_W$, temperature $T_W$, and surface area $S_W$ is surrounded by dry air at standard pressure and some hotter temperature $T_A > T_W$.  Assume that the air is so convective and effectively infinite that the air in contact with the water surface:

Always stays dry (i.e., 0% Relative Humidity), and
Maintains its temperature $T_A$ and pressure.

How can we calculate the rate of change of $T_W$?  I.e., will the water get colder or hotter?
I think that this scenario is sufficiently simple that we only need to calculate the rates of cooling due to evaporation and heating due to convection.
